# algorithm game theory

Tags: matrices

$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{T}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3& 3 & 0 \\
        4 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 4 & 5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Every Nash equilibria of this game is symmetric, that is, $x = y$, where $xT$ is one
of $(0, 0, 1), (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}), \text{or} (\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4},0)$. Follow the LH paths starting at $(0, 0)$for all missing labels, and explain what you observe.

My question is:
Why it is enough to consider the missing labels 1, 2 and 3.
please can anyone help me out?